# Flutter plugin - Attempt to invoke virtual method on a null object reference

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

I am learning how to create [Flutter Plugins](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages) so I decided to create a Bluetooth plugin, I know there are many available out there but the purpose here to learn.

The error I am facing is as following

```
E/MethodChannel#flutterpluginbluetooth(22072): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#flutterpluginbluetooth(22072): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.Intent android.content.Context.registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver, android.content.IntentFilter)' on a null object reference
```

I am not a Java developer and this I am sure is not the pretty approach so just ignore the approach for now.

This is my `onMethodCall`

```
  @Override
  public void onMethodCall(@NonNull MethodCall call, @NonNull Result result) {
    if (call.method.equals("getPlatformVersion")) {
      result.success("Android " + android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
    } else if (call.method.equals("getMessage")) {
      BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
      result.success("hello");


      System.out.println("DEBUG - Starting discovery");
      bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
      final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          System.out.println("DEBUG - inside onReceive");
          String action = intent.getAction();
          System.out.println("DEBUG - Action is: " + action);
          //Finding devices
          if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            System.out.println("Device Name: "  + device.getName());
          } else {
            System.out.println("DEBUG: Action did not match"  + BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
          }
        }

      };
      IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
      System.out.println("DEBUG - About to registerReceiver");
      context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);


    }
    else {
      result.notImplemented();
    }

  }
```

The question I have is why I am getting an error on this `context.registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);`

I am also reading the [android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth#SettingUp) documentation and that is calling `registerReceiver` without any context and if I try that approach I get an error as well which is as following which occurs during the compile time.

```
error: cannot find symbol registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
```

This is `onAttachedToEngine`

```
  @Override
  public void onAttachedToEngine(@NonNull FlutterPluginBinding flutterPluginBinding) {
    channel = new MethodChannel(flutterPluginBinding.getFlutterEngine().getDartExecutor(), "flutterpluginbluetooth");
    channel.setMethodCallHandler(this);
  }
```

Regarding `Context`

I am just importing it

```
import android.content.Context;
```

and inside a class I am declaring a `context` variable

```
private Context context;
```

I will really appreciate some help here.

Comment: How do you get your context? Please post the entire class or at least `onAttachedToEngine`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem you're initilasing `context`, you can do that using `flutterPluginBinding` inside `onAttachedToEngine` such as;

```
context = flutterPluginBinding.getApplicationContext();
```